# InMemory Option in SSAS MultiDimensional

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, cube, olap-cube

Messing around with the storage options in a test SSAS Multidimensional model in SSDT on my home computer in sql server 2012 developer edition, and looking at the different partition storage options. If you pick the normal storage settings "hyperlink" button You get a dialog with the options from ROLAP and MOLAP everything in between. or you can choose "custom setting" and click the "options" button in the bottom right. In which case you can choose MOLAP, HOLAP, or ROLAP.
This is all expected, however if you right click on a partition and choose properties, in the properties window for the StorageMode you can get an option for InMemory.

[image]

After choosing this, the value for the storage mode for that partition will be blank.

[image]

I thought this was only a SSAS tabular setting. Researching online only talks about this setting in tabular mode. Anyone know what is happening here and maybe some documentation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a bug in the Dev tools. That relates to Tabular as you suspected and won't work with Multidimensional. Just disregard it.